# Simpler groupStartBy function?

Tags: haskell

I am writing the following function the second time in unrelated projects (first was XML processing, now custom command line flag processing), and I have a feeling that it should exist in some library, I just cannot find it.  It groups list elements, each group starting at an element where a predicate is true.

Any simpler ways to do this?

```
groupStartBy :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupStartBy pred xs = reverse $ map reverse $ foldl' step [] xs
  where
    step as x | pred x = [x]:as
    step (a:as) x = (x:a):as
    step [] x = [[x]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `groupBy` to do this:

```
import Data.List (groupBy)

groupStartBy :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupStartBy pred = groupBy (const (not . pred))
-- or in point free style: groupStartBy = groupBy . const . (not .)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [split package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/split/0.1.1/doc/html/Data-List-Split.html) can be very useful here. I haven't found something that has the exact same functionality as your function, but if you play around with some of the basic functions I'll bet you could get what you're looking for. `splitWhen` is similar but drops the elements that satisfy the predicate. `split . whenElt` is a little closer but separates the predicate elements into different elements of the new list.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, something like:

```
groupStartBy :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupStartBy f = split (dropInitBlank . keepDelimsL . whenElt $ f)
```

if I understood you correctly. `split`, `dropInitBlank`, `keepDelimsL` and `whenElt` are from [Data.List.Split](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/split/0.1.1/doc/html/Data-List-Split.html).